# Why are these mod_rewrite rules not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, infinite-loop

I have an `.htaccess` file that looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(\d+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1&num=$2 [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically, I'm trying to write an API that can handle requests like `get_all/` or `get/123/`.

The problem is, when I try to go to either of the above URLs, the `cmd` parameter is always set to `index.php` and the `num` parameter is not set at all.

If I comment out either of the `RewriteRule` lines, then requests work for the remaining, uncommented out RewriteRule, but I need to be able to handle both cases.

I am aware of the looping that occurs with `mod_rewrite`, but in this case, I have no clue how to stop it. I can't even understand why the above rules are causing `cmd` to be set to `index.php`.

Can anyone please explain what is happening here and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe just by adding "RewriteBase /" under RewriteEngine On if you are in a subfolder and use a subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are behaving because `RewriteCond` is only applied to very next `RewriteRule`. Due to this your last `RewriteRule` is running without conditions and hence running twice by `mod_rewrite` loop.

Use this code to fix it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(\d+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1&num=$2 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to avoid repetition of `Rewriteond` then use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # skips files and directories from rewrite rules
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(\d+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1&num=$2 [L]

  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Once again, you saved the day! Thank you so much. I get why the first one works, but how does the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` in the second one work?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means do nothing if above conditions work i.e. file or directory check.

Comment: anubhava, thanks again for all your help and explanations. Unfortunately, the second solution (the one without the duplicate `RewriteCond` lines) does not work. Any clue why? Thanks.

Comment: The first works great, but when I copy and paste the second one into my `.htaccess` file, it doesn't work. I can't test it this very second, but I'll note the error later (I believe it's a 404).

Comment: Did you have 2 `RewriteCond` lines before `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`? I have been using it on my live website without any problem.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. It did work. I must have not copied and pasted it correctly the first time, as it didn't work before, but now it does. Not sure why, but works great now. Thanks again.